# jquery getting child element values

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a dumb question, but im stuck. Why does my first one work but not the other 3. From reading the docs, all 4 should do the job. I want to in a bigger use case get an element of a form, there could be other elements on the same page with same name inside other forms or in other divs, so the 4th option is what I really want to work. But I cant figure out why all these dont work.

http://jsfiddle.net/7vF5z/1/

html:

```
 <form id="filter_form_id" name="filter_form" method="get" action="/retrieved_data_records">

 <select id="brand_id" name="brands">
 <option value="0"></option>
 <option value="143272526">Brand1</option>
 <option selected="selected" value="269998788">Brand2</option>
 <option value="330516076">Brand3</option>
 <option value="330516077">Brand4</option>

 </select>
</form>
```

js:

```
 alert ("The val: " +  $('#brand_id').val() );    
 alert ("The val: " +  $('brands').val() );  
 alert ("The val: " +  $('#filter_form_id brands').val() );  
 alert ("The val: " +  $('#filter_form_id > brands').val() );
```

Comment: Is the 4th form supposed to be a child selector?

Comment: `From reading the docs` which docs are you reading? o_O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selectors use `brands` as if it's an element name.  You need to use an attribute selector like `[name="brands"]`.

Updated testcase: http://jsfiddle.net/7vF5z/3/

```
alert ("The val: " +  $('#brand_id').val() );    
alert ("The val: " +  $('[name="brands"]').val() );  
alert ("The val: " +  $('#filter_form_id [name="brands"]').val() );  
alert ("The val: " +  $('#filter_form_id > [name="brands"]').val() );
```

---

> the 4th option is what I really want to work

If that's supposed to be a child selector, then you need to correct it by:

- Using the correct child selector syntax
- Using an attribute selector, as in my example.

There's no real reason to use a child selector there, unless you're going to have multiple controls with that same `name` value in that same form.

Comment: Not sure why you selected the other answer as correct (or why it has more upvotes), but FYI, mine was earlier. It keeps showing the "mins ago" times wrong and flip flopping the order, but if you hover over "mins ago" it shows the actual time.

Comment: seemed like his was first but if yours was thats fine with me, both great answers!

Comment: @Joelio: Remember there's no rule on StackOverflow that the first answer has to be accepted. It's the answer you (the OP) found most helpful... whether it was fhe first by miles or last by a week.

Answer (score 8):

Where are you getting these selectors from?

1. `$('brands').val()` is looking for elements whose `nodeName` is `brands` (none of them). To check the name attribute use `$('[name="brands"]').val()`
2. `$('#filter_form_id brands')` is looking for elements whose `nodeName` is `brands` (none of them) which are descendants of an element whose ID is `filter_form_id` (definitely none of them).
3. `$('#filter_form_id => brands')` is completely invalid. If you want the child selector you want `$('#filter_form_id > brands')`

For more complete documentation check the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for available selectors.

Answer (score 2):

Because with plain string like `brands`, jQuery will look for a tag with that name. And `brands` is not a tag. What you can do otherwise is, `$('select[name="brands"]').val()`

Answer (score 1):

```
// OK
alert ("The val: " +  $('#brand_id').val() );
// there is no tag <brands />
alert ("The val: " +  $('brands').val() );  
// there is still no tag <brands />
alert ("The val: " +  $('#filter_form_id brands').val() );
// KO, doesn't mean anything
alert ("The val: " +  $('#filter_form_id => brands').val() );
```